# PUT me/tracks returning 402 error

Tags: ios, sdk, spotify

Our awesome app that uses Spotify (over a year in development!) is getting to the finish line but are working through a specific Spotify snag.

We have a button that toggles the "saved" status of the currently playing track.  For a track that is already saved DELETE + me/tracks + ids= works as expected.  However, using PUT with the *same* url and ids param results in the error "Request failed: bad request (400)".  This is also 100% reproducible for a track that has not been previously saved (I cite the DELETE working above to demonstrate that the url, param, auth, and process is setup correctly).

Please advise, thanks!

Comment: Does the user maybe reached the limit of 10000 items? What about the returned error object?

Comment: Definitely not hitting that 10k limit.

Comment: Correction to the error: 400 { URL: https://api.spotify.com/v1/me/tracks } { status code: 400, headers {
    "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" = true;
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers" = "Accept, Authorization, Origin, Content-Type";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Methods" = "GET, POST, OPTIONS, PUT, DELETE";
    "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" = "*";
    "Access-Control-Max-Age" = 604800;
    "Cache-Control" = "private, max-age=0";
    Connection = "keep-alive";
    "Content-Encoding" = gzip;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Mon, 29 Feb 2016 20:05:47 GMT";

Comment: To be clear, the *same* block of code is used to un-save tracks (via DELETE) and the request completes without error.

Comment: I tied adding 'type' / 'track' params to the PUT request and no change

Comment: @DrewO'Meara can you try filling https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/console/put-current-user-saved-tracks/ with your ids and access token?

Comment: Looks like my PUT was placing the params in the body rather than in the request string so that was it.  Thanks for your help!